# Are the main thread and the UI thread same in C# WPF application?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Can you start the UI from another thread rather than in main thread? So heavy processing in the main thread would not block the UI is that possible?

C# 4.5 WPF application

Comment: What do you mean by Main thread? That's what we normally call the UI thread.

Comment: @EmperorAiman i agree with you but even my university instructor get confused and doesnt know that :D

Answer (score 4):

Yes they are the same thread.  You would want to spawn off a new thread to handle major processing.

The following example simply has a button that will sleep (for 10 seconds) the main thread, once the Button_Click is called and the "sleeping" begins the whole UI becomes unresponsive.

Hope that helps.

.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="231,142,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>

</Grid>
```

.cs

```
    using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
        }
    }
}
```

Edits include grammar correction and explanation of sample/example code.

Answer (score 1):

The thread on which we call `Application.Run` (Or whatever mechanism you start WPF) is the UI thread. Normally, this is the thread which your application starts at.

If you want heavy processing without blocking the UI thread, you should do it in a new thread. Here's an example:

```
private async void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(1000)); //Assume Thread.Sleep is your heavy processing
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by the main thread. If you mean the thread that runs `Main()`, then it's possible. You just need to spawn it, make it STA and call `Application.Run()` as you would do in `Main()`.

Moreover, WPF can have multiple UI threads, thus having multiple dispatchers. Each UI thread can access the elements that were created from the current thread only (and with the current thread's dispatcher).

If you want to avoid blocking the UI thread, then that is not the case, consider using `async\await` instead.

Comment: so each ui having its own unique thread? or all share the application started main thread?